# Motor Voltage For Trike

Tags: motor

I am fairly new to electrical engineering, and I am planning to build an electric reverse trike.
I am planning to buy a 3kw hub motor from uumotor.com (Model number UMB3K). It states that it can on 48 to 96v. I need to decide what voltage to use, so that I can start building my battery. Anyways, my question is, if I choose a higher voltage, will it run faster, or maybe have more torque? And would it then draw less amps? 
Thanks.

Comment: This is not the right place for your question.  You should find a forum where enthusiasts share *experiential* knowledge in the building of electric vehicles, ideally of the type you want or at least the type of light electric motorcycles often referred to as "e-bikes".

Comment: @user208427 Look at the torque curves for the motor on the datasheet, they usually relate speed, torque and current

Answer (score 1):

According to the [performance data](https://www.uumotor.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/UMB3K-testing-data-72V3000W.pdf), the motor produces over 3 kW (actually 3.7 kW @ around 90% efficiency) at 72V and 60A. Pretty impressive!

If you cut the voltage in half, you will cut the available power by at least half as well, because you still won't be able to exceed 60A — this limit is set by the resistance and power dissipation of the windings.